# How to set line numbers by default in vim?

Tags: macos, vim

I know you can add line numbers in vim by using,

```
:set number
```

How do I set this to default behavior?

Comment: Put `set number` in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Open `.vimrc` in a text editor, type the characters `set number` and save the file.

Comment: more importantly, [read the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html)

Comment: Thanks for that documentation, I will take a look!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

add this line to ~/.vimrc (if not exist, create a new file)

```
:set nu
```

and save the file

Comment: Since you only have to enter it once, there's not much point in abbreviating it. It's going to be easier to read if you use `set number` (the `:` isn't needed in `.vimrc`).

Answer (score 2):

the settings in `$HOME/.vimrc` file would be loaded automatically.

Except for `set number` to show linenumber, I have this to toggle normal line number and relative line number: (by pressing `<leader>nu`)

```
"---------------------------------------------------------
"toggle relativeline number
"---------------------------------------------------------
function! ToggleRelativeNumber()
    let &relativenumber = &relativenumber?0:1
    "let &number = &relativenumber? 0:1
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>nu :call ToggleRelativeNumber()<cr>
```

https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/.vimrc#L704

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `/etc/vim/vimrc` (in sudo mode) and add the following line: `set number`

By the way, you will also find other (highly recommended) interesting commands you can enable:

```
" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd             " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch           " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase         " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase          " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch          " Incremental search
"set autowrite          " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden             " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a            " Enable mouse usage (all modes)
```